# how can I input multi line string in yii?

Tags: text, input, yii

I want to make a yii program to add some name to my database at once.
so I need an input field that can get multi line/ multi row. so I can input some name, and then input to databases. how can I do that? how can I make text field (this is default field from yii) to get multi line input string? or do i need to use other than text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called textarea, after the appropriate HTML tag.

[`CActiveForm::textArea()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#textArea-detail)

[`CHtml::textArea()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#textArea-detail)